# Cygwin make command - gcc error : No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make, windows-7-x64

I installed cygwin with gcc, g++, make and gdb to my windows 7 computer. Whenever I try "make --version" command I get the following error[make error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EwN0.png). Removing and reinstalling cygwin did not help. Other packages are not giving this kind of error.

I had previously installed cygwin and may not have properly removed it. Some settings may be still present which I cannot find. Please help me find the problem with this "make" command.

Comment: Please cut and paste error messages (properly formatted) into questions instead of attaching pictures.  This doesn't appear to be output from `make`.  It looks like output from a batch file.  Maybe there's a `make.bat` in this directory or on your `PATH` somewhere that's being invoked instead of the `make.exe` program?

Comment: @MadScientist You are correct, I found a make.bat which was creating this issue. Thank you!